# Count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string using Bash?

**EXAMPLE:**

I'd like to know how many times this substring :

```
Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

...occurs in this string...

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
113: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

**NOTE I:** I have tried several approaches with sed, grep, awk... Nothing seems to work when we have strings with spaces and multiple lines.

**NOTE II:** I'm a Linux user and I'm trying a solution that does not involve installing applications/tools outside those that are usually found in Linux distributions.

---

**IMPORTANT:**

I would like something like the hypothetical example below. In this case we use two **Shell variables (Bash)**.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
STRING="0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
113: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no"

SUB_STRING="Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no"

awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{str=$0; next} {print gsub(str,"")}' "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"
```

**NOTE:** We are using awk just to illustrate!

Comment: do you have `-P`(Perl) flavor in your `grep` supported?

Comment: should the string with only spaces (without linebreaks) `Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no` also be counted?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Unfortunately not. =| Thank you! =D

Comment: what's your `grep --version`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest "without linebreaks" -> We need to use the exact string. =D

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest "what's your grep --version" -> The approach used has to work on several different distributions (Ubuntu Server, CentOS, OpenSuse, Docker containers, etc). The grep version used on my Desktop machine is this: "grep (GNU grep) 3.1".

Comment: Thanks for crossposting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207325/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string/50210382#50210382

Comment: Complex question... In reality this could be solved with a "crossover questions" feature in order to allow one question to be included in multiple stackexchange sites. Other than that, a superuser user, for example, suggests "You probably will find more help on Stack Overflow, the SE site for programmers". We were then between the "cross and sword"... Should we not multiply a thread and thus not reach as many people as possible? I do not particularly see problem with this, it happens on the internet all the time. At the end of the day, see how many contributions were possible! Thank you! =D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
printf '%s' "$SUB_STRING" |
  perl -l -0777 -ne '
    BEGIN{$sub = <STDIN>}
    @matches = m/\Q$sub\E/g;
    print scalar @matches' <(printf '%s' "$STRING")
```

With `bash` alone, you could always do something like:

```
s=${STRING//"$SUB_STRING"}
echo "$(((${#STRING} - ${#s}) / ${#SUB_STRING}))"
```

That is `$s` contains `$STRING` with all occurrences of `$SUB_STRING` within it removed. We find out the number of `$SUB_STRING`s that were removed by computing the difference in number of characters in between `$STRING` and `$s` and dividing by the length of `$SUB_STRING` itself.

POSIXly, you could do something like:

```
s=$STRING count=0
until
  t=${s#*"$SUB_STRING"}
  [ "$t" = "$s" ]
do
  count=$((count + 1))
  s=$t
done
echo "$count"
```

Comment: The pure bash approach works perfectly apart from being fully portable to various Linux distributions including Docker containers and so this was the best answer so far. =D

Comment: nicely done on the bash-only solution

Answer (score 7):

If the substring contains no line breaks:

```bsh
echo -n STRING | grep -Fo SUBSTRING | wc -l
```

Comment: Great solution. Just one small tweak, use grep -Fo:

`echo $STRING | grep -Fo SUBSTRING | wc -l`

Comment: @presto8 I previously removed the `o` flag, erroneously thinking it was unnecessary. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

Using string processing functions we could do it with Perl as follows :

```
 printf '%s\n' "$STRING" |
 perl -nse '
      $_ .= join "", <>;
      $k++ while ++($p = index($_, $s, $p));
      print $k, "\n" ;
 '    --     -s="$SUB_STRING"
```

Explanation:

```
° load up the whole string in $_

°  index function will return the position of a substring in a string OTW returns -1

° progressively match the substring and use the position found as the starting position for the next search. 

°  all this while increment the counter $k depicting substring found.
```

Some other methods are listed below:

Slurp the string and use regex.

```
printf '%s\n' "$STRING" |
perl -slp -0777e '
        $_ = () = /$s/g;
 ' -- -s="$s"
```

°  Slurp string into the $_ variable.

°  pass the substring from the command line to perl using the -s option.

°  now perform a match on $_ and in a list context gets you the matches which are then take in scalar context to get the number of matches.

°  the -p option shall autoprints what's in $_.

Method using the sed tool :

```
 esc_s=$(printf '%s\n' "$SUB_STRING" |\
 sed -e 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g' -e 'H;1h;$!d;g;s/\n/\\n/g')

 printf '%s\n' "$STRING" |
 sed -ne '
         $!{N;s/^/\n/;D;}
         /'"$esc_s"'/{
               x;p;x
               s///;s/^/\n/;D
         }
 ' | wc -l
```

° As a preparatory step, we go ahead and escape all characters acting as meta characters to the left hand side of s/// statement in the substring which if not done will cause the sed to crash.

°  Now we slurp the whole of string into the pattern space.

°  then we keep printing an empty line, the hold space is a good candidate, and take away the substring from the pattern space.

°  rinse... lather... repeat so long as substring is present.

°  the empty lines are then piped to the wc tool which will get us the count of lines = number of times substring was found.

This is shell version:

```
 e=$STRING  N=0
 while 
     e=$(expr " $e" : " \(.*\)$SUB_STRING")
     case $e in "" ) break ;; esac
  do
           N=$(expr "$N" + 1)
  done
  echo "$N"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Won a "UP" for the excellent explanation. Approach with perl. Additionally the author made his code aiming at performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-given-substring-in-a-string)

```
python -c 'print "abcdabcva".count("ab")'
```

Or if you are working with shell variables:

```
python -c 'print("""'"$STRING"'""".count("""'"$SUB_STRING"'"""))'
```

In your case:

```
python -c 'print """0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
                   Soft blocked: no
                   Hard blocked: no
          1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
                   Soft blocked: no
                   Hard blocked: no
          2: phy0: Wireless LAN
                   Soft blocked: no
                   Hard blocked: no
          113: hci0: Bluetooth
                   Soft blocked: no
                   Hard blocked: no""".count("""Bluetooth
                   Soft blocked: no
                   Hard blocked: no""")'
```

Comment: Will look great If you can do it in a way that does not need to escape the line breaks. An approach with python has great value! =D

Comment: @EduardoLucio challenge accepted and answer edited :)

Comment: The following example worked perfectly for me (Python 3): `python -c 'print("""'"$STRING"'""".count("""'"$SUB_STRING"'"""))'`. Note that in this example we pass the bash/shell variables "directly" to the python command. I think this template is compatible with Python 2 and 3. My suggestion is that you update your answer with this "improvement".

Answer (score 2):

```
gawk '
END { print NR - 1 }
' RS='Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no' input.txt
```

**Explanation**

`RS` - the input record separator, by default a newline. Set it to the required string and `awk` will split all text to records, using this string as separator. Then, it remains only to print the number of records subtracted by `1` in the `END` section.

**Using variables:**

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING='0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
113: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no'

SUB_STRING='Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no'

gawk 'END { print NR - 1 }' RS="$SUB_STRING" <<< "$STRING"
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to use Shell variables (see in my question) with your approach if it is possible. Could you modify it to work that way? Thanks a lot! =D

Comment: @EduardoLucio See update. I added version with variables usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you have gnugrep, you can run something along the lines of

`grep -zPio 'Bluetooth\s+Soft blocked: no\s+Hard blocked: no' ex.txt | grep -zc .`

Comment: If your string is (example) " Soft blocked: no" or "Soft blocked: no" with "\s+Soft blocked: no" match result becomes indifferent to the spaces of the original string entered. We need the count to be made by the exact substring entered. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the exact substring replace the `\s+` flexible spaces by strict spaces `...\n      Soft blocked: no...`

Comment: I did the test with the following command `echo -n "$STRING" | grep -zPio 'Bluetooth\n         Soft blocked: no\n         Hard blocked: no' | grep -zc .`. However, the match remains indifferent to the number of spaces. Thanks! =D (NOTE: The stackexchange editor is removing the spaces I've placed!)